# URL issue with sub directories

Tags: html, css, resolveurl

I am creating a website with server side includes, and have multiple directories.
For example in the **head.html**(it's an include) I am pointing the stylesheets as **href="css/style.css"** and it's works fine in the home page. but when I am trying to run a page inside the **event** (a folder/subdirectory) it's not taking the stylesheet. can anybody solve this out.

It's a pure HTML static website, can we use anything like clientResolveUrl or something like that?

Comment: try like this `href="/css/style.css"`

Comment: Thanks @SureshPonnukalai , I thried `href="/css/style.css` too. but it's not getting. When i tried to set as `href="../css/style.css"` which worked with the page inside event, but not with the page inside the root folder.

Comment: are the css folder in root? and what is the protocol that you use? `http://` or `https://` or `file://`

Comment: @Kyojimaru presently I am working with localhost. I set up localhost in my PC using Wampserver.

Comment: Absolute URL such as `/css/style.css` _should_ work equally well on root and deep pages. If it does not then you are missing something.

Comment: @Shafee did your url like `http://localhost:port/event/test.html`?

Comment: @Kyojimaru http://localhost:81/event/index.html

Comment: @Shafee what is your folder project name in `www` folder? try change `/css/style.css` to `/folder_name/css/style.css`, if it's working, you probably should create a `Virtual Host`

Comment: @Kyojimaru thanks it's worked when I tried with the folder name.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating your project folder inside `\wamp\www\sitename` and include the css using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

it will target the root folder, that is `www` in your case, not the `sitename`, so you should write it like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sitename/css/style.css" />
```

but, you should probably use a `Virtual Host` so you can write it like the 1st one in your live site, here's the [forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123740,123866) that explain how, and why you should be better using a `Virtual Host`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use your browser's *web tools* to check the path to that CSS file (or simply read the source code on your browser). You may then notice whether a subdirectory, or the parent directory, is missing from the relative path.

You may then need to change so that it becomes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="event/css/style.css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />
```

depending on the actual structure of files and directories.

Comment: Thanks fro your reply, first of all there is no css folder inside the **event** folder, so the first option won't work. But when I tried to use the second one which worked with the page inside the **event** folder, not worked the pages directly inside the root folder.

Comment: OK; for pages inside your *root* directory, the path should then be `css/style.css` instead. Right? Each page should specify the relative path to `style.css` according to its own position in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I think `<base>` tag can help in this case.

> **Definition and Usage**
>
> The  tag specifies the base URL/target for all relative URLs in a document.
>
> There can be at maximum one  element in a document, and it must
>   be inside the  element.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp